# Symfony3 on Google App Engine Flexible can't connect to Google Cloud SQL MySQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, symfony-3.3, google-app-engine-php, symfony3.x

I can't get my Symfony 3 project on Google App Engine Flexible to connect to Google Cloud SQL (MySQL, 2. Generation).

Starting off with these examples

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/symfony

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/cloudsql-mysql

I created a Google App Engine and a Google Cloud SQL (MySQL, 2. Generation), both at europe-west3.
I tested out these examples on my GAE and both run fine.

Then I went on and created a new, very simple Symfony 3.3 project from scratch.
After creation (with only the welcome screen and "Your application is now ready. You can start working on it at: /app/") I deployed that to my GAEflex and it works fine.

After that I added one simple entity and an extra controller for that.
This works fine, as it should, when starting Googles cloud_sql_proxy and the Symfony built-in webserver "php bin/console server:run".
It reads and writes from and to the Cloud SQL, all easy peasy.

But, no matter what I tried I always get a "Connection Refused" on one (or the other, depending of my state of experimentation) of the commands from "symfony-scripts" "post-install-cmd" in my composer.json.

"$ gcloud beta app deploy" output (excerpt)

```
...
Step #1: Install PHP extensions...
Step #1: Running composer...
Step #1: Loading composer repositories with package information
...
Step #1:     [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
Step #1:     An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
Step #1:
Step #1:
Step #1:     [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
Step #1:     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
Step #1:
Step #1:
Step #1:     [PDOException]
Step #1:     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
...
```

parameters.yml (excerpt)

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: gae-test-project
    database_user: root
    database_password: secretpassword
```

config.yml (excerpt)

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        unix_socket: '/cloudsql/restof:europe-west3:connectionname'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

composer.json (excerpt)

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "chmod -R ug+w $APP_DIR/var",
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
```

app.yml (complete)

```
service: default
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: web

env_variables:
  SYMFONY_ENV: prod
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: secretpassword
  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/restof:europe-west3:connectionname;dbname=gae-test-project
  WHITELIST_FUNCTIONS: libxml_disable_entity_loader

#[START cloudsql_settings]
# Use the connection name obtained when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "restof:europe-west3:connectionname"
#[END cloudsql_settings]
```

Keep in mind that I added or altered only lines which examples and documentation advised me to.

What Do I do wrong?
The examples both work fine, a Symfony project connecting to the DB through a running cloud_sql_proxy works fine, when I try to get doctrine to connect to a CloudSQL from within an GAEflex I get no connection.

Can anyone spot the rookies mistake I might have made?
Has anyone had this problem and maybe I forgot one or the other setting with the GAE or CloudSQL?
Can anyone point me to a repository of a working Symfony3/Doctrine project that uses GAEFlex and CloudSQL?

I am stuck as I can't find any uptodate documentation about how to get this, rather obvious, combination to run.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers /Carsten

Comment: I'm not familiar with Symfony, but what happens if you remove the host/port lines from config.yml? The error message ("Connection refused
") suggests that it's trying to connect over TCP rather than using the UNIX socket.

Comment: You're right about the "Connection Refused" hinting to TCP but, nope, then it says "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory". Did I mention that I been pondering this for days now? After I couldn't find an example I willy nilly tried everything I could think of, short of rolling my head on the keyboard. That's why I asked if someone can definitely point to my mistake or a project which works.

Comment: Can you double check that you have enabled the Cloud SQL API? See point 2 under "Before you begin" here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-sql

Comment: Vadim ^_^ please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it.
I read this post [Flexible env: post-deploy-cmd from composer.json it not being executed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/lCyykFUgXFc) which yielded two interesting infos.

1. App Engine Flex for PHP, doesn't run `post-deploy-cmd`any more
2. just use `post-install-cmd` as a drop-in replacement, unless you need DB connection.

So, during deployment, there is simply no database connection / socket available!
That's why Google introduced the (non-standard) `post-deploy-cmd` which unfortunately seems to have caused some other trouble, so they removed it again. Bummer.

In effect, as of to date, one can't use *anything* that utilizes the database within post-install-cmd.

In the case above, I just changed

composer.json (excerpt)

```
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "pre-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "chmod -R ug+w $APP_DIR/var",
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
```

And everything runs fine...

I'm not sure about the innards of `installAssets` and if I still achieve the originally intended effect when I move it to pre-install but, well, it works for a very simple example application...
In the next days I'm going to work on carrying this over to my more complex application and see if I can get that to work.

Further discussion will most likely be over at the [Google Cloud Platform Community](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/issues/262)

Cheers everyone!